# Operator precedence: why parse unary operators this way?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I'm following along with Bob Nystrom's great book "Crafting Interpreters".

Please let me know if this question is too specific for this site - I've been trying for hours but couldn't figure this out on my own :)

In chapter [Compiling Expressions](http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/compiling-expressions.html), in function `unary()`, the function `parsePrecedence(Precedence)` is called with `PREC_UNARY` instead of `PREC_UNARY + 1`.

The book explains this is in order to enable "nesting" of unary operators. E.g.: `--1`.

However, in `parsePrecedence(Precedence)` no precedence level is checked before parsing *prefix* operators - it is checked only before *infix* ones. And `unary` is a prefix parser.

So passing `PREC_UNARY` or `PREC_UNARY + 1` to `parsePrecedence(Precedence)` doesn't seem to make a difference. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better to ask this question directly to the tutorial's author. Alternatively, you could abstract away the context of the question and ask a general question about handling prefix operators in a Pratt parser. Nonetheless, I tried to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you are right: with this particular grammar, there is no difference because no binary (or postfix) operator has precedence `PREC_UNARY`, and the test that will be used is ≤.

All the same, the conventional answer is to use `PREC_UNARY` because unary prefix operators are (necessarily) right associative. This convention comes from the case of binary operators, where you need to use the operator's precedence plus one for left associative operators (the normal case) and the operator's precedence itself for right-associative operators (exponentiation and assignment, for example). (Assignment is actually somewhat more complicated, but I personally think the solution proposed by Bob Nystrom is more complicated than would have been necessary.)

Another conventional answer derives from the possibility of using a bottom-up operator precedence parser (Dijkstra's "shunting yard") instead of the top-down Pratt parser. Fully exploring bottom-up parsing goes well beyond the scope of this question; suffice it to say that the same principle applies with respect to associativity.